# Finding the a subgraph that is a binary tree and contains all nodes

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I have a non-oriented graph and I have to find a subgraph that is a binary tree and contains all nodes of the graph.

The only solution that I know is to generate all subgraphs that are trees and print the first one (or the only one) that has same number of nodes as the initial graph. (even so I don't really know how to do it)

The starting node can be any node.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to get is a spanning tree or maybe a minimum spanning tree.
Refer to this for more details or google about spanning tree:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree

Comment: I think it's called the maximum spanning tree but my problem is that my tree has to be binary

Comment: i think you can modify a spanning tree algorithm like Prim's algo to check for binary tree constraints like not more than 2 edges are going out and not more than 1 edge coming in and so on.. and then perform some operations accordingly.